# Git Mege Conflict modify/delete

Tags: git

I made a mistake with my git repo and need some help resolving it, as my git foo isn't that great. I have two branches I'm working on: `EBT_Branch` and `Scheduling_Branch`. I had some changes on on `Scheduling_Branch` that I wasn't ready to commit jus yet, so I ran `git stash` and `git checkout EBT_Branch`. I then made a commit and ran `git checkout Scheduling_Branch` and `git stash apply`, which yielded the following error that I can't figure out how to resolve:

```
On branch Scheduling_Branch
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    deleted by us:   dump.rdb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Before I was getting an error telling me I couldn't merge binary files, so I tried running `git rm dump.rdb` to remove it from git, and then ran `git stash apply` again, which is how I wound up with the above message.

At some point I accidentally committed my Redis server's `dump.rdb` file. I later added it to my `.gitignore`, but now I can't seem to get rid of it. What I would like to know is how can I get rid of `dump.rdb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the stash you created includes stashing changes to `dump.rdb`, but you're trying to apply that stash to a branch where `dump.rdb` has been deleted. When Git tries to apply the stash, it wants to apply the stashed change to `dump.rdb`, but can't as the file doesn't exist. That's what producing the message you're seeing.

To resolve the merge conflict, just run `git rm dump.rdb` again. After you've done that, the message you're seeing should disappear from the `git status` output.

Of course, any time you try to apply that stash again, you'll see the same message, because the stash still contains the changes to `dump.rdb`. The quickest way to fix that is to replace the stash with one that doesn't record changes to that file. Do that by using `git stash apply` to apply the stash, `git stash drop` to drop the stash you just applied, `git rm dump.rdb` to resolve the conflict, then `git stash save` to create the new stash.

(Two brief asides for completeness: 1. You could alternatively use `git stash branch` to create the new stash, which is sometimes useful when dealing with merge conflicts in applying a stash. I don't think that helps here, though, given we know how to easily resolve the merge conflict. 2. Normally it's quicker to use `git stash pop` which does both `apply` then `drop`, but in this case `pop` will refuse to `drop` since there are merge conflicts, thus `apply` and `pop` are identical in behaviour.)

To explain the `.gitignore` behaviour: once you've added a file to Git, Git ignores whether it's in `.gitignore` or similar – it assumes that since you've committed it, you don't want to ignore it. To get `.gitignore` to actually cause Git to ignore the file, you need to remove it from Git's view of the repository.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks! I was able to clear `dump.rdb` out of my Scheduling_Branch.